# EF Core Add-Migration doesn't work - Build failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have simple DbContext with single DbSet:

```
class SimpleDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Content> Content { get; set; }

    public SimpleDbContext()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("DbConnectionString"));
    }
}
```

Also I have created asp.net core (.net framework) project and class library as data access layer. In Package Manager Console I made data access project as default and web project as start up.
I installed Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools on data access project.
But when I ran Add-Migration command package manager said:

```
PM> add-migration test
This command may fail unless both the targeted project and startup project are ASP.NET Core or .NET Core projects.
Build failed.
```

I thought it's because I use usual Client Library for data access. I created new Client Library (core) project and did the same things(also updated project.json - added Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools to tools section as said in tutorial https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/full-dotnet/new-db.html). Line:

> This command may fail unless both the targeted project and startup
>   project are ASP.NET Core or .NET Core projects.

Disappeared but Build failed left.

Anyone knows what could it be or how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding .Net Core Client Library project and changed framework to .Net Framework 4.6.1 instead of .NETStandart